# I want common header and footer all over pages

Tags: header, custom-headers

I have included following  to make it done. But Javascript elements on page are not working due to this.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $.get("header.html", function(data) {
    $("#header").html(data);
       });
     });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"></div>
<content>
</content>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should add that onload not on document ready

Comment: javascript elements in the current page or the ones present in the header.html ?

Comment: I hav to add .js file link in header.html file otherwise Javascript elements are nt working which are present in header file. AND if I do so den it affects js elements on current page in which I hav included header file. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you can manage to setup a virtual server like XAMPP on your machine, then using PHP, you can include header and footer on just any page you want with a single line of code.

```
<header><?php include 'header.php';?></header>
```

and footer with

```
<footer><?php include 'footer.php';?></footer>
```